# How to use OrderBy in Linq using xpath

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 `IEnumerable<XPathNavigator>` and I want to sort it by child value.

```
item1 = from XPathNavigator item in iterator1 select item;  
item2 = from XPathNavigator item in iterator2 select item;

item1 = item1.Union(item2);

item1.OrderBy(res => int.Parse(GetNavigatorValue(res, "./item[@value='ParentId']")));

static string GetNavigatorValue(XPathNavigator iterator, string xpath)
{

   XPathNodeIterator inner = iterator.Select(xpath);
   inner.MoveNext();
   return inner.Current.Value;
}
```

It doesn't work.

How do I use `OrderBy` in Linq if I need to sort it by xpath?

Thanks,
user460397

Comment: @user460397: Beside that this XPath expression `./item[@value='ParentId']` could be better `item[@value='ParentId']`, this question is only LINQ (the framework library) and C# (the host language) related.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the problem? Shouldn't it be

```
item1 = item1.OrderBy( ... );
```

?